# Is there a better way to have dynamic text appear next to a combobox?

Tags: extjs

I have a combobox, and based on the current selection, I would like dynamic text to appear beside the combobox.
My current solution works, but seems kludgy and fragile.  It may not work at all depending on where the combobox appears in the DOM.
Here is the crux of my current solution (called when dropdown changes):

```
    var child = owner.el.first().next().first().first().first().next().first();
    if (child.dom.childNodes.length == 3) {
        child.createChild({
            tag: 'span',
            html: c + Ext.id()
        });                      
    } else {
        child.last().replaceWith({
            tag: 'span',
            html: c + Ext.id()
        });
    }
```

I'm mostly concerned about the first line...this can't be a good way of finding an insertion point.

Here is a pic of the combo box with the dynamic text appearing beside:

[image]

And here is what I looked at to find where I wanted to insert the text:

[image]

Can someone suggest a better way of achieving this effect?  Thanks.

Comment: You can use ToolTip Widget of ExtJS.

Comment: @Cybernate: Thanks for the suggestion, but that just shows something on hover.  I want text on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the span in the page already and grab it by its id.

```
Ext.get('combo-suffix').insertHTML(theText);
```

Or, grab the combo box element by its id and get/add its sibling.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I can't have the span "in the page already" - it needs to be embedded inside a Combo box (or I need some really tricky CSS with it to physically stick it as if it were inside the inner wrapper for the combobox).  The 2nd suggestion seems more promising, but it's sibling is the input text field & doing this inserts the text between the input field and the dropdown icon.  What I think I need is it's sibling's sibling.  ...any suggestion for getting that?

Comment: Ok, found a better solution using your 2nd suggestion.  I'll post it as and answer (just for completeness), but give you the credit.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Will it always be in a div called "ext-gen82"?

If so, why not use the jquery find method?

```
$("#ext-gen82").find("ext-gen107");
```

Alternatively you could give them their own class to help you find them as well:

```
$(".parentClass").find(".spanElement");
```

You could also use the children method:

```
$("#ext-gen82").children("span");
```

Comment: Haha.  1.  I'm using Extjs - I wouldn't add an entire other library to do this (since Extjs could do this too).  2.  The names are dynamic - no guarantee they'll be the same each time

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't catch that! :)

Answer (score 0):

@OrangeDog pointed me the right direction, but I'll post a more detailed answer here for completeness/future reference.

```
var inserted = false; // need to set this up initially
...
var pos = Ext.getCmp('combo-element-id').el.next('.x-form-trigger');
if (inserted) {
    pos.next().update(c + Ext.id());
} else {
    inserted = true;
    pos.insertSibling({
        tag: 'span',
        html: c + Ext.id()
    }, 'after');                            
}
```

Comment: I think my main issue with this was that I wasn't initially able to get class selectors like .next() to work since I was leaving off the '.' in front of the class (I was looking for classes like 'x-form-trigger', not '.x-form-trigger')

Comment: You should probably only insert the new element once (when rendering the form) and then in future just grab it by id (or depending on code structure, maintain a reference to it)

Comment: @OrangeDog: ...seems a bit much for me to add an onRender just to add this once, but I will update my answer to just update the content instead of creating it new each time.  Thanks again.